appendrow adds blank rows
I have this simple script that is intended to take data from one sheet to another in the same workbook. It works, but it also adds about 1,000 empty rows before the data rows. Once I get this working, I want to add code to clear the data out of the 1st sheet.
How can I get this to stop adding all the blank rows?
function moveRows() {

       //collect the data
       const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
       const source_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Working Sheet");
       const datarange = source_sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
      //console.log("datarange ",datarange);

       //append the data
       const destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Processed");
       destSheet.appendRow(datarange);
       

     }

Here is a link to an example spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1scteZbJfs6171pyigUWgYmI9jAAi0HfDrKv_IJfKJLY/edit?pli=1&gid=953131243#gid=953131243

Would you be able to provide your sample sheet, with your initial output, and also your expected output so that we can further help you. You may use this anonymous sheet maker to create your reproducible example without your email being exposed.

Here's the example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1scteZbJfs6171pyigUWgYmI9jAAi0HfDrKv_IJfKJLY/edit?pli=1&gid=953131243#gid=953131243

While a link to a spreadsheet might be helpful, please remember that questions on Stack Overflow should be self-contained. Please [edit] the question to add the link to it, and add any important detail directly into the question body.

@Wicket I added the spreadsheet link to the original question. I think the question has all of the information that it needs. I appreciate the guidance, I'm new to Stack Overflow.

Make sure to provide input and expected output as plain text table in the question. Check my answer or other options to create a table easily, which are easy to copy/paste.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question useless for others or images, which are hard to copy. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.

The method append row method of Class Sheet accepts pararamters one dimensional arrays.  getValues() returns a two dimensional array.

Moving Rows from Sheet to Another Sheet
For starters your appendrow(), after your data taken doesn't make sense I assume that this is the error you are encountering because it will just create 1 row of data with the number of columns corresponds to your rows which I don't think is not your expected goal. I created a code to correctly transfer data keeping the format of the data structure, it clears the contents and all the contents will be added after the lastRow on Processed Sheet.
Sample Code:
function moveRows() {

   //collect the data
   const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   const source_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Working Sheet");
   const datarange = source_sheet.getRange(2,1,source_sheet.getLastRow(), source_sheet.getLastColumn());
   var data = datarange.getValues();
  datarange.clear()


   const destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Processed");
   var destRange = destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length);
   destRange.setValues(data)

 }

Sample Output:



Sample










Sample
Sample
Sample
Sample
Sample
Sample
Sample


Sample
Sample
Sample
Sample
Sample
Sample
Sample


Sample
Sample
Sample
Sample
Sample
Sample
Sample


Sample
Sample
Sample
Sample
Sample
Sample
Sample


Sample
Sample
Sample
Sample
Sample
Sample
Sample


Sample
Sample
Sample
Sample
Sample
Sample
Sample


Sample
Sample
Sample
Sample
Sample
Sample
Sample


secondSetofSample
secondSetofSample
secondSetofSample
secondSetofSample
secondSetofSample
secondSetofSample



secondSetofSample
secondSetofSample
secondSetofSample
secondSetofSample
secondSetofSample
secondSetofSample



secondSetofSample
secondSetofSample
secondSetofSample
secondSetofSample
secondSetofSample
secondSetofSample



secondSetofSample
secondSetofSample
secondSetofSample
secondSetofSample
secondSetofSample
secondSetofSample



secondSetofSample
secondSetofSample
secondSetofSample
secondSetofSample
secondSetofSample
secondSetofSample




Reference:
Range Clear
setValues()

Thanks so much for this. I tried the code and it removed everything from the Working Sheet (including the first row, which contains the field names), and did not move the information to the Processed sheet. I provided a sample spreadsheet, here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1scteZbJfs6171pyigUWgYmI9jAAi0HfDrKv_IJfKJLY/edit?pli=1&gid=953131243#gid=953131243

@DinaBarnese Please [edit] the question to mention on it all the relevant details.

@DinaBarnese I adjusted the code so it would skip over the header rows. You said it did not move the information I used the previous code and it moves the data and delete it on the working sheet based on your posted question? By any chance you have different sheet name?

@Babanana Thank you, thank you! The code works perfectly, what I found was that it appended way down the sheet, after the "ghost rows" that my code had added. This works perfectly. I appreciate your time!!

If your question is resolved please post the solution as an answer so that other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.
